# stepMinute not working in PrimeNG's Calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the time picker with PrimeNG's Calendar and have the following code:

```
<p-calendar class="due-time" name="time-due" timeOnly="true" showTime="showTime" hourFormat="12" stepMinute="15" readonlyInput="readonlyInput" 
            [(ngModel)]="TimeDue" (ngModelChange)="updateTimeDue()"></p-calendar>
```

This all works fine, except for the fact that I want the minutes to increment/decrement by 15, and despite adding `stepMinute="15"`, as seen above, the minutes still increment/decrement by 1. I tried changing that to `[stepMinute]="15"`, but that gave me the following error:

> Can't bind to 'stepMinute' since it isn't a known property of
>   'p-calendar'.
>   1. If 'p-calendar' is an Angular component and it has 'stepMinute' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'p-calendar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

If I change that to `[attr.stepMinute]="15"`, then it gets rid of the error, but it goes back to going up and down by 1. How am I supposed to get `stepMinute` to actually work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- angular@2.4.3
- primeng@2.0.0

---

Both examples (stepMinute="15" and [stepMinute]="15") works well.

What version of PrimeNG's Calendar are you using?